# How do you share a database connection between API routes in NextJS 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to connect my NextJS 13 app to my MongoDB Atlas backend but am having difficulty finding a way to share the MongoClient object between my API route handler route files. I don't want to open a new connection each time I make an API call as I'd imagine this is inefficient and believe I've seen this advised against.

How can I share one connection between routes?

I've looked at [this guide](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/nextjs-with-mongodb/) which uses the code found in one of the [official NextJS examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/lib/mongodb.ts), but I don't believe that multiple files importing an exported object reference the same object (at least not in NextJS, as I've tried a toy example where I export a simple variable and observe whether mutations to that variable are reflected in different route.ts files).

I also don't believe I can use a provider as I would have to mark any files that need the DB connection with 'use client' which has performance implications.

If there are better ways of implementing something like what I'm trying to do, please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

we don't share database connection. each api function connects and disconnect. We still check if the connection alive, if it is alive, we use it if not we create new connection. [This article explains well](https://www.kevincunningham.co.uk/posts/dealing-with-a-database-with-nextjs-api-routes/)

> ### Why are things different in a serverless world?
>
> With Next, each API route is deployed as a serverless function. As one
> of these routes is accessed, the function spins up and processes the
> request. For some time after that request, the environment remains
> active.
>
> Previously, we have been able to assume that the connection is alive.
> Now, like Schrödinger’s cat, it could be either alive or dead – until
> we observe it.
>
> So, our code needs to check if there is a connection. If there is an
> active connection then we return to our API component, allowing it to
> access the connection through mongoose. If there is not an active
> connection, then we need to create the connection and then pass back
> control.
>
> Since every API route is atomic, we can’t tell if this function has
> been called already. This means that we need to check for the database
> status in each route rather than centrally.
>
> ### What happens in high traffic situations now?
>
> We had three options previously – more connections, more servers, more
> caching. Each of these options required manual configuration or
> intervention. It was also hard to match the provisioning to our actual
> needs. We either had too much or too little – rarely hitting the
> Goldilocks point.
>
> Now that every route is handled separately and serverlessly, our
> environments will automatically provide more of that route if it is
> needed. We no longer have to manage these traffic interventions
> manually. We don’t have to keep a server up and running when we don’t
> need it. We also don’t have to provide a whole new server if it is
> only one or two routes that are being requested more often.

Comment: Is MongoDB still an appropriate backend choice with this being the case, given that each api request will require a new MongoClient / DB connection? I’m struggling to fully understand the implications it has on the appropriateness and best practices of my backend choice.

Comment: best choice depends on the business logic. even you postgres and connect thrugh prisma, you still have to call prisma client in each api

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/nextjs-with-mongodb/

Comment: Thank you. I actually reference that link in my question and it’s a useful guide, but I don’t fully understand it. It says that it “caches the instance of our connection so that subsequent requests do not have to reconnect to the cluster” but I don’t understand how the corresponding code achieves that.

Comment: main thing is since api functions are serverless, those serverless functions are not active all the time. that means connection cannot be active all the time neither. that is why in each request we check if connection exist if not we create a new connection